# MCMC Image Processing Example in Matlab or Python

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing

I am looking for a sample code that utilizes Markov Chain Monte Carlo method for image processing, preferably for segmentation, in Matlab or Python. Except for the MRP ICM.m example, I was not able to find any. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- http://healthyalgorithms.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/mcmc-in-python-pymc-to-sample-uniformly-from-a-convex-body/
- http://notendur.hi.is/eches/research.html
- http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Teaching/CS340-Fall06/reading/mcmc.pdf

Comment: The ~murphy and healthyalgorithms links did not have image processing code, but it is a very good source on MCMC with lots of Matlab code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From Mumford's Pattern Theory book samples

http://www.dam.brown.edu/ptg/MDbook/

this chapter

http://www.dam.brown.edu/ptg/MDbook/Chapter4.html

has Ising model and MCMC (Gibbs sampling).

Also

http://elec.otago.ac.nz/w/images/1/19/ELEC404_Inverse_Problems.pdf

I found that searching for "imread", "MCMC", "Hastings" provides good results.