# Examples/tutorials of Adaptive Metropolis for images using PyMC

Tags: image-processing, python-3.x, bayesian, pymc

I am looking for examples or tutorials of the [`AdaptiveMetropolis`](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelfitting.html#the-adaptivemetropolis-class) step method used for  image processing.

The only vaguely image-related resource that I have found until now is this astronomy [dissertation](http://www.asu.edu/clas/hst/www/jwst/ASUdissertations/MMechtley_Thesis.pdf) and the related GitHub [repo](https://github.com/mmechtley/psfMC).

This wider [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984188/mcmc-image-processing-example-in-matlab-or-python) does not seem to provide PyMC example code.

What about finding the peak on this simulated array?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sz = (12,18)
data_input = np.random.normal( loc=5.0, size=sz )
data_input[7:10, 2:6] = np.random.normal( loc=100.0, size=(3,4) )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
im = ax.imshow( data_input )
ax.set_title("input")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I know of is here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter5_LossFunctions/LossFunctions.ipynb (see
Example: Kaggle contest on Observing Dark World)

On this thread you asked a specific question: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/653 about finding an array in an image. Here is a first attempt at a model:

In that case it seems like you are trying to estimate a 2-D uniform distribution with gaussian noise. You'll have to translate this into an actual model but this would be one idea:

> lower_x ~ DiscreteUniform(0, 20)
>
> upper_x ~ DiscreteUniform(0,20)
>
> lower_y ~ DiscreteUniform(0, 20)
>
> upper_y ~ DiscreteUniform(0, 20)
>
> height ~ Normal(100, 1)
>
> noise ~ InvGamma(1, 1)
>
> means = zeros((20, 20))
>
> means[[lower_x:upper_x,lower_y: upper_y]] = height # this needs to be
> a deterministic
>
> data ~ Normal(mu=means, sd=noise)

It might be better to code upper_x as an offset and then do lower_x:lower_x+offset_x, otherwise you need a potential to enforce lower_x < upper_x.